# Avoid "Allow full screen" in HTML5

Tags: html, browser, fullscreen

In Youtube , on clicking full-screen [Even in Private Browsing] "Allow full screen" will not appear.

Anyway to do like video on fullscreen

Comment: Is it possible that youtube is serving you the flash version of a video?

Comment: "Allow full screen" is there for a reason. Having an option to circumvent it would defeat its point entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The `Allow Full Screen` dialog appears out of security reasons and can therefore not be turned of. This prevents websites scamming users. Check out this article for more information: http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/

Youtube is able to show you videos in full screen without asking because the videos are delivered with flash which can bypass the browsers security limitations.